# How to remove monitors from list of sound output devices?

Tags: macos, display, airpods

In my list of sound output devices I have

```
MacBook Pro speakers
Dell U2720Q
Dell U2720Q
My AirPods Pro
```

Sometimes my Mac switches output device to one of the monitors. I don't know when but I guess that it is when I take off my airpods.

I never want to use the monitors as sound output device. Is it possible to stop this from happening?